Do any 3 positive numbers accept the lengths of the bisectors of the angles of a triangle?
A few minutes ago I was trying to add up the properties of the inner bisectors of the angles of a triangle, and while I was doing that a question came to my mind, is any three positive numbers suitable for the lengths of the bisectors of the angles of a triangle?
We know that three lengths accept the lengths of the Median sides of a triangle if they accept the side lengths of a triangle $m_a+m_b>m_c>|m_a-m_b|$, and we know that three numbers accept the lengths of the heights of a triangle if their reciprocals accept the side lengths of a triangle $\frac{1}{h_a}+\frac{1}{h_b}>\frac{1}{h_c}>|\frac{1}{h_a}-\frac{1}{h_b}|$, but for the inner bisectors I feel that there is nothing to do except that we have three positive numbers, am I right?
How to prove it if it is true?
In any case, are there references on the subject, I searched the internet a little and did not find anything

Perhaps you will find this post of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51087/triangle-from-lengths-of-angle-bisectors

@fleablood I believe the OP refers to the problem of constructing a triangle given the lengths of it's 3 bisectors. If so, the comment above leading to an existing post here should provide an answer.

Was not familiar with that branch of questions at all.  Interesting.

What is meant is, if a, b, c are any three positive real numbers, can a triangle exist such that the lengths of its angle bisectors are a, b, c?  I mean, aren't there any restrictions that need to be placed on the numbers a, b, and c? @fleablood

My question is different, my question talks about existence and not construction. @MathematicianByMistake

No restrictions are needed on the numbers. That's what the answer to the other question says.

You're right, @Ted.
